OpenSearch Dashboards behind nginx reverse proxy
I want to deploy self-hosted opensearch behind nginx reverse proxy.
I started with the example docker-compose.yml:
services:
  opensearch-node2:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest
    container_name: opensearch-node2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - DISABLE_INSTALL_DEMO_CONFIG=true
      - DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://opensearch-node2:9200"]'
      DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN: true
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  r-proxy:
    image: nginx
    container_name: r-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
    hostname: r-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80

volumes:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:

default.conf is simple
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  nginx.internal;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://opensearch-dashboards:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding *;

        proxy_buffer_size       256k;
        proxy_buffers           4 512k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
        proxy_hide_header       X-Content-Type-Options;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

I also added nginx.internal  127.0.0.1 record to the local /etc/hosts.
OpenSearch dashboards are available at the URLs http://localhost, http://localhost:5601, and http://nginx.internal:5601. But accessing it via http://nginx.internal shows OpenSearch Dashboards did not load properly. Check the server output for more information. message and page does not load.
What configuration forces opensearch-dashboards to not load on a custom domain?

Removing proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding *; from the proxy config solved the problem
